# How to avoid the violation of the unique key by the updating in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am developing an ASP MVC 5 and ADO.net.
Trying to Edit (Update) the properities of the user (client) via a stored procedure, I got always a sql exception with the Id's parameter :

When I delete it, the exception is :

> Procedure or function 'UpdateClientsInfo' expects parameter '@CltId', which was not supplied.

And when I add the CltId, it will show me :

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Client__A9D1053400F8EEAC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Client'. The duplicate key value is (user@user.com)."

Basing on the search in many forums, I tried to add this line but it didn't work:

> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Here is my controller :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Client cmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientManagement cdb = new ClientManagement();
            if (cdb.UpdateDetails(cmodel))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Client Details Edited Successfully";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
```

and here is the ClientManagement Class :

```
  public bool UpdateDetails(Client cmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateClientsInfo", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CltId", cmodel.ClientId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", cmodel.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", cmodel.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", cmodel.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", cmodel.Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", cmodel.Address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", cmodel.Password);

            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (i >= 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        catch (SqlException sqlexc)
        {
            foreach (SqlError error in sqlexc.Errors)
            {
                string msg = string.Format("{0}: {1}", error.Number, error.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

the model Client :

```
 public class Client
{


    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    [Range(0, 15)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
    public String Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The DB schema for the stored procedure :

```
 CREATE procedure [dbo].[UpdateClientsInfo]  
(  
   @CltId int,
   @FirstName nvarchar (50),  
   @LastName nvarchar (50),  
   @Email nvarchar (50),
   @Phone nvarchar(50),
   @Address nvarchar(50),
   @Password nvarchar (max)  
)  
as  
begin  
   Update Client   
   set 
 FirstName=@FirstName,  
 LastName=@LastName,
 Email=@Email,
 Phone=@Phone,
 Address=@Address,
 Password=@Password
End
```

a Code's snippet from the view Edit :

```
body style="background-image: url('/template/web/images/fd.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Client", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal" runat="server">


        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted full implementation of said procedure?

Comment: @borkovski you mean stored procedure, yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your stored procedure, you basically try to update every single record in db. Try to put where as below sample

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateClientsInfo]  
(  
     @CltId INT,
     @FirstName NVARCHAR(50),  
     @LastName NVARCHAR(50),  
     @Email NVARCHAR(50),
     @Phone NVARCHAR(50),
     @Address NVARCHAR(50),
     @Password NVARCHAR(max)  
)  
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Client   
    SET FirstName = @FirstName,  
        LastName = @LastName,
        Email = @Email,
        Phone = @Phone,
        Address = @Address,
        Password = @Password
    WHERE CltId = @CltId
END
```

Comment: btw, i just realize, your Email column is actually a unique column. You might have to check if the email if exist proceed to update. or else, error will be thrown. try update with different email that not exist in db. pretty sure you can update.

Comment: Yes it is an unique key but I resolved with a remote validation, I don't think that is the problem